# Node with Typescript problem with nodemailer

Tags: typescript, nodemailer

I have a problem with nodemailer in Typescript. I downloaded the package via

```
npm install --save @types/nodemailer
```

everything installed correctly, everything is in node_modules, package.JSON dependencies has an entry. When I call the

```
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
```

file it transposes the tsc and starts the node file.js everything is ok ... but when I add a function call to this file it throws an error "Cannot find module 'nodemailer'. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just installed the type definitions but not the library itself.

You also have to install

```
node install --save nodemailer
```